# Matrix with a certain property related to rank

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have a matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ that has a rank of $r$ and a property of any $r$ columns of $A$ are linearly independent. Does this kind of matrix have a special name? Do they have other intriguing properties?

Comment: I doubt that there's a special name.  You could rephrase the property as: all nonzero vectors in $\ker(A)$ have more than $r$ nonzero entries.

Comment: This is called the “Kruskal rank” of the matrix, and it comes up frequently when working with tensor decompositions.